# How to update composer in PHP

Tags: php, api, composer-php

I'm new to the composer I'm using a plugin here they used composer. I getting some errors that the reason I want to update composer because might be an issue with the composer i'm not sure what is the issue here. my question is in my plugin composer is already installed. Are there any other things I have to install in local?

How should I update this composer used in the plugin?

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/codehaiku/envato-purchase-code-verifier

here I just download the plugin and added my token and API but when I was entered purchase code I was getting an error `Invalid Purchase Code`. Can anyone suggest me is there any other alternative way to this instead of using this plugin some other plugins?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From the error that you specified in the question, it doesn't look like an issue with compose but the Purchase Code. Have you used the purchase code previously?

Comment: @Muhammad Asif yes I used already its working fine.

Comment: If I'm not wrong a purchase code can only be used once. If you've already used a purchase code, then you'll get the error "Invalid Purchase Code" for sure.

Comment: @ Muhammad Asif no not like this i want to get user info anytime once go through  this http://ezcode.pt/themes/EPCVerify/ like this

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as asked:

composer self-update

However, if you're worried that the composer file could be bad download a new version [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

If you pay attention to the steps you'll eventually be at one where there's a file called `composer.phar` in the directory you ran it (probably in your webroot/public_html folder) and then you can be sure you're using the new version by using the command

```
php composer.phar update
```

that will update your libraries.

On a potentially more helpful note, contact the vendor as your key may, legitimately, be wrong and/or you purchase an invalid code from a 3rd party.

Comment: the key is valid it is working in another side. And I go to through the plugin directory and passed this command `php composer.phar update` getting an error  `php is not recognized as an internal external command`

Comment: potentially it's a single seat licence and as this request is coming from another IP it's being returned false.

Comment: i think issue not with the composer can you please find what might be the issue here.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure it's a legitimate licencing issue. Contact your vendor.